# Media player play next song after completion of the first one

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I want to make a program that will automatically play the next song after the one ends variables;

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Music/";
String[] fileArray;
public int songNumber = 0;

MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
public boolean isPlaying = false;
public boolean isPaused = false;`
```

the void is;

```
 private void playMusic(String song){
    if(!isPlaying) {
        try {
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                    songNumber = songNumber + 1;
                    playMusic("/mnt/sdcard/Music/" + fileArray[songNumber]);
                }

            });

            mPlayer.reset();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), song, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(song);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener((OnCompletionListener) this);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception of type : " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;
    }else{
        stopMusic();
    }
}
```

However nothing is working, after the first song ends nothing happens

Comment: because you have defined `isPlaying` as global variable, which is set `true` at first time. And you are not changing it inside `onCompleteListener`. Set `isPlaying = false` inside `onCompleteListener`. Hope it will work fine.

Comment: @Saikat1529 Nah.. It did not work

Comment: Do I need any third party application on my android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code on the void to this

```
private void playMusic(String song){
    if(!isPlaying) {
        try {
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                    isPlaying = false;
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    songNumber = songNumber + 1;
                    playMusic("/mnt/sdcard/Music/" + fileArray[songNumber]);
                }

            });
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), song, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(song);
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception of type : " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;
    }else{
        stopMusic();
    }
}
```

Is gonna fix the problem